# Finding the equilibrium conditions for the Chebyshev approximation problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

$$-x_0 ≤ \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j-b_i ≤ x_0 $$ 
$$ i=1,...m$$  $$\mathrm {min} x_0 $$

(Forgive me if I made any formatting mistakes; I'm not familiar with MathJax)

I know better than to try and use this website as a "homework answers" forum, but I'm honestly not sure where to start. Am I supposed to do something with the Duality Principle?

Comment: Do you mean optimality conditions? Or complementarity conditions?

Comment: The question asks specifically for equilibrium conditions despite there being no references as to what such a condition is in the textbook :/

Comment: I am also not aware of such term in linear programming. I know that game theory equilibrium can occasionaly be interpreted as strong duality in linear programming. But I do not believe that this is what the authors mean here.

Comment: If I'm being honest, I'm not quite sure what the question is asking. Thank you for reading my question. If you're at all curious, the textbook is "Methods of Mathematical Economics: Linear and Nonlinear Programming, Fixed Point Theorems" by Joel N. Franklin.